# How to run a function before route is displayed in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, routes

I am trying to do the equivalent of Laravel Middleware for my WordPress site.

I am implementing a real time notification system and when a user clicks on a notification, there will be query string `?read`

So I will have url like `myapp.net/lesson/some-lesson?read`

I need to tap into WordPress somewhere so that I can check the url and mark off in my database that the message was read so that when the lesson page loads the notification is already cleared. Searching for route related hooks isn't pulling up anything useful.

What can I try next?

Comment: Maybe [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/)? (Except that you won't be doing a redirection, just do your database action and then let WordPress continue loading as normal.)

Comment: That makes sense for sure. Will try that out!